# how to parse a JSON data in side a table layout dynamically?In Android from a URL

Tags: android, json, parsing, listview

I am Parsing a a JSON data from a URL..
I followed [this](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parsing-yql-using-json-tutorial/) tutorial to parse the dynamic JSON data

now am parsing the data,.
in a List view.. when I click on that list view a New Item view will appear in that I want to add some contents which are form a JSON data.. But its viewing the last one of the data So I parse it with a string format but I am getting the data in string but I want that data in a table..

this is my JSON data`{
    "request": "ok",
    "query": {
        "result": [
            {
                "details": [
                    {
                        "offers": [
                            {
                                "id": "UUkY8",
                                "model": "XL"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "UUkY8",
                                "model": "XXL"
                            }
                        ],
                        "count": 2,
                        "url": "http://www.wallmart.com"
                    },
                    {
                        "offers": [
                            {
                                "id": "NNkz4",
                                "model": "XL"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "NNkz4",
                                "model": "XXL"
                            }
                        ],
                        "count": 2,
                        "url": "http://www.amazon.com"
                    }
                ],
                "flag": [
                    "http://www.donkersct.nl/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/stackoverflow.png"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}`

and I am parsing that in this way

```
JSONArray json_results_details =c.getJSONArray("details");
                      System.out.println("looping json_results_details");
                      String strOffermodel="";
                        for (int j = 0; j < c.length(); j++) {
                            System.out.println("looping json_results_details[" + j +"]" + "json_results_details.length() -->" + json_results_details.length());

                            if (j < json_results_details.length()) {

                                JSONObject d = json_results_details.getJSONObject(j);
                                stridsName += d.optString("name")+",";
                                stridsURLs += d.optString("url")+",";

                                // Get site details

                                long lOffer_Counts =-1;
                                try {
                                    lOffer_Counts= Long.parseLong(d.optString("offers_count"));

                                } catch(Exception e) {
                                    lOffer_Counts =-1;
                                }                               
                                strOffersCount+= String.valueOf(lOffer_Counts) + ",";

                                if(lOffer_Counts > 0) {

                                    JSONArray json_offers = d.getJSONArray("offers");
                                    System.out.println(json_offers.toString());
                                    String strmodel="";
                                    for (int k = 0; k < json_offers.length(); k++) {


                                         JSONObject e = json_offers.getJSONObject(k);

                                          map.put("id", e.optString("id"));
                                          map.put("model", e.optString("model"));
                                          strmodel += e.optString("model") + "$";
                                      }  
                                    strOffermodel += strmodel + ",";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    strOffermodel += ",";
                                }

                                map.put("id", stridsName);
                                map.put("model", strOffermodel);
                               }
                         }
                        arraylist.add(map);
```

So no I am getting the Model in loop.

as `Model:XL,XXL/XL,XXL...`

I tried with list view but failed now I am trying with table View..
But I want the output should be as

[image]

Here Only one id is showing I want all ID and all Model as a comperation..
Please help me to find out I am using a table inside a listviw, I tried with Listview inside a Listview.. But not worked..

I tried with increment the data means ID/Model with for loop as i+1 But its incrementing the value
means I am expected as

```
    map.put("id", strOfferid);
    map.put("id1", strOfferid1);
    map.put("id2", strOfferid2);
    map.put("id3", strOfferid3);
```

But I am incrementing the value like

```
Model:XL1,XXL1/XL2,XXL2/XL3,XXL3
```

So any one please help Regarding this..

Comment: yes  user2967727 sir, But I am parsing forma  already running server so I cant make any modifications on server side..

Comment: Can you post the code where you fill the table? Also, does your map object fills up correctly?

Comment: Nice User3152691 you can Loop the data Loop ur ud,model as id1,Model1.. So that You can able to display the data...

Comment: Sir Can any One Help me.. How to add or where to add that Loop I mean I don't know how to add Loop on JSON name when I add its incrementing value to XL1,XXL1,XL2,XXL2.. But I am not changing the server side data I mean Lable Model.. as Model1,model2..

Answer (score 0):

use instead of

```
JSONObject d = json_results_details.getJSONObject(j);
```

this

```
JSONObject d = new JSONbject(json_results_details.getJSONObject(j));
```

Comment: Hello Boopathi sir , I am Able to display the entire data But at the second part.. I am expecting like the data of ID and Model should be repeates similar like rank and populatin but its overwriting...